# appContext.startActivity - Is it a good idea?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-task

I been told that starting activity from application context is bad idea, and you should prefer using activity context where possible.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, MyActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    appContext.startActivity(intent);
```

So I read Google article about tasks: [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).
It says that each stack got its [taskAffinity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff) id, and if new activity will be lunched with **taskAffinity** id that belong to already running task, than it will be placed in that task(if lunch mode is default or single top).

So if you didn't declare **taskAffinity** id for your activity, it will not matter if you lunching your activity from app context or activity context.

But once again, I been told that using app context to start new activity is a bad practice. So please tell me, why is that so? Do I missing important cases where I should pay attention to?